# Cordova: Cannot add android platform, getting EACCES Error

Tags: android, node.js, cordova

I've installed Cordova using `sudo npm install cordova` and set up the paths (I believe) correctly. When I run `cordova platform add android` I am receiving the following error:

> Error: EACCES, open
>   '/home/millerbr/.cordova/lib/npm_cache/cordova-android/3.6.4/package/.npmignore'

I've been looking at other similar problems, and a few solved theirs using "chown" on the folders relevant to their problem - is there something similar I can do for this?

Comment: Do you have an existing project folder?

Comment: Yeah, that's where I'm running the command from

Comment: Have a look at this post: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16151018/npm-throws-error-without-sudo/24404451#24404451

Comment: Had a look at that topic, one of the other replies led me to using `chown` to fix the issue, thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As it turned out, it was indeed a permissions issue. Running `sudo chown -R $(whoami) ~/.npm` seems to be allowing me to progress